# Compare Football Picks with other players across weeks

Tags: mysql, similarity

I have a football pool website. Each week, my friends pick the winners of each game. I want to  compare the picks of each player to the other players and list the percent similar. I found this page which helped me calculate the Similarity for a specific week: [Compare group of tags to find similarity/score with PHP/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446308/compare-group-of-tags-to-find-similarity-score-with-php-mysql). Kudos to [Ivar Bonsaksen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365119/ivar-bonsaksen), his solution worked great!

What I want to do now is show the cumulative **Similarity** of each player for the past weeks.

I have 3 tables to query: Profiles (spprofiles), Games (sp6games), and Picks (sp6picks). Another table called Teams (sp6teams) is used to get the name of the team, but is irrelevant here.

```
Profiles (spprofiles)
+-----------+-------------+
| profileID | profilename |
+-----------+-------------+
| 52        | My Team A   |
| 53        | Some Team B |
+-----------+-------------+

Games (sp6games)
+--------+--------+---------+------+
| gameID | weekID | visitor | home |
+--------+--------+---------+------+
| 1      | 2      | 9       | 21   |
| 2      | 2      | 14      | 6    |
| 17     | 3      | 6       | 9    |
| 18     | 3      | 30      | 21   |
+--------+--------+---------+------+

Picks (sp6picks)
+-----------+--------+------+
| profileID | gameID | pick |
+-----------+--------+------+
| 52        | 1      | 21   |
| 52        | 2      | 6    |
| 52        | 17     | 12   |
| 52        | 18     | 21   |
| 53        | 1      | 9    |
| 53        | 2      | 6    |
| 53        | 17     | 9    |
| 53        | 18     | 21   |
+-----------+--------+------+
```

The query for the current week looks like this:

```
$weekID = 3; //the current weekID
$profile = 52; //the current ProfileID

SELECT
  targetProfiles.profileID AS targetID,
  sourceProfiles.profileID AS sourceID,
    COUNT(targetProfiles.profileID)
    /
    (((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sp6Picks LEFT JOIN sp6Games USING (gameID) WHERE profileID = sourceProfiles.profileID AND weekID = $weekID)
      +
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sp6Picks LEFT JOIN sp6Games USING (gameID) WHERE profileID = targetProfiles.profileID AND weekID = $weekID))/2)
  AS similarity
FROM
  spProfiles AS sourceProfiles
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT sp6Picks.* FROM sp6Picks LEFT JOIN sp6Games USING (gameID) WHERE weekID = $weekID) AS sourcePicks
    ON (sourcePicks.profileID = sourceProfiles.profileID)
  INNER JOIN
    (SELECT sp6Picks.* FROM sp6Picks LEFT JOIN sp6Games USING (gameID) WHERE weekID = $weekID) AS targetPicks
    ON (sourcePicks.pick = targetPicks.pick AND sourcePicks.profileID != targetPicks.profileID)
  LEFT JOIN
    spProfiles AS targetProfiles
    ON (targetPicks.profileID = targetProfiles.profileID)
WHERE sourceProfiles.profileID = $profile
GROUP BY targetID
```

If I run this query on the weeks separately I get the following results:

```
$weekID = 2;
+----------+----------+------------+
| targetID | sourceID | similarity |
+----------+----------+------------+
| 53       | 52       | 0.5000     |
+----------+----------+------------+

$weekID = 3;
+----------+----------+------------+
| targetID | sourceID | similarity |
+----------+----------+------------+
| 53       | 52       | 0.5000     |
+----------+----------+------------+
```

The query I've worked out so far for the cumulative looks like this (but I've tried several other variations). Basically, I just changed the WHERE clauses to include earlier weeks `weekID <= $weekID` and added the Games table to the main FROM clause `LEFT JOIN sp6games ON (targetPicks.gameID = sp6games.gameID)`.

```
$weekID = 3; //the current weekID
$profile = 52; //the current ProfileID

SELECT
  targetProfiles.profileID AS targetID,
  sourceProfiles.profileID AS sourceID,
    COUNT(targetProfiles.profileID)
    /
    (((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sp6Picks LEFT JOIN sp6Games USING (gameID) WHERE profileID = sourceProfiles.profileID AND weekID <= $weekID)
      +
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sp6Picks LEFT JOIN sp6Games USING (gameID) WHERE profileID = targetProfiles.profileID AND weekID <= $weekID))/2)
  AS similarity
FROM
  spProfiles AS sourceProfiles
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT sp6Picks.* FROM sp6Picks LEFT JOIN sp6Games USING (gameID) WHERE weekID <= $weekID) AS sourcePicks
    ON (sourcePicks.profileID = sourceProfiles.profileID)
  INNER JOIN
    (SELECT sp6Picks.* FROM sp6Picks LEFT JOIN sp6Games USING (gameID) WHERE weekID <= $weekID) AS targetPicks
    ON (sourcePicks.pick = targetPicks.pick AND sourcePicks.profileID != targetPicks.profileID)
  LEFT JOIN
    spProfiles AS targetProfiles
    ON (targetPicks.profileID = targetProfiles.profileID)
  LEFT JOIN sp6games ON (targetPicks.gameID = sp6games.gameID)
WHERE sourceProfiles.profileID = $profile
GROUP BY targetID, weekID
```

The combined results should be 0.5000, but instead I get:

```
$weekID = 3;
+----------+----------+------------+
| targetID | sourceID | similarity |
+----------+----------+------------+
| 53       | 52       | 0.7500     |
+----------+----------+------------+
```

The problem is the `COUNT(targetProfiles.profileID)` is not totaled correctly across the weeks and therefore the `similarity` value is messed up. It also seems to not be very efficient with larger datasets.

Thanks for taking the time to read, and possibly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT   t.profileID                 AS target,
         SUM(s.pick=t.pick)/COUNT(*) AS similarity
FROM     sp6picks s
    JOIN sp6picks t USING (gameID)
    JOIN sp6games g USING (gameID)
WHERE    g.weekID    <= 3
     AND s.profileID != t.profileID
     AND s.profileID  = 52
GROUP BY t.profileID
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5d12/2/0).

Comment: Wow, thanks. So deceptively simple. Really sucks when the solution takes less time to write than the question!

Comment: How would I modify this to get results of every player vs every player for a single week? Removing the `AND s.profileID  = 52` only returns 1 result per person.

Comment: @Itlan: You need to group on both players: `SELECT s.profileID AS source, t.profileID AS target, SUM(s.pick=t.pick)/COUNT(*) AS similarity FROM sp6picks s JOIN sp6picks t USING (gameID) JOIN sp6games g USING (gameID) WHERE g.weekID = 3 AND s.profileID != t.profileID GROUP BY s.profileID, t.profileID`.  Note that if you don't want/need the same results to appear both ways around (e.g. for 2 vs 1 and 1 vs 2) then you can change the inequality filter from `s.profileID != t.profileID` to `s.profileID < t.profileID` or similar.