# Grouping similar news contents together like in GOOGLE NEWS

Tags: php, rss, cluster-analysis, feed

I am unable to manage the RSS feeds easily due to an overwhelming number of new stories / similar news contents posted in various news sites. For subjects such as world news and business news, many of the stories are redundant, adding a burden to readers to sort out which stories they've already read. To deal with the twin problems of flooding and redundancy, i need to develop an code that reduces the number of items to read and uses the overlapping information to divine interesting topics.

*it would be easier if i am able to Grouping similar news contents together like in GOOGLE NEWS / StackOverflow and present it to the users.*

Comment: Are the *topic categories* (sports, world, entertainment, health...) *pre-determined*? In other words, do you now already how to group the news items?  (If yes, this is a supervised learning problem) Or is that up to the user(s) to specify how many and which topic-categories there are? (=> unsupervised => more difficult)

Answer (score 10):

This is definitely a not-so-easy-to-solve problem that can be solved by:

- smart text-parsing functions
- raw hardware power
- both of them
- testing, testing, testing
- fine-tuning at the end

First of all i'd group different news sources to some relatively broad category. You can easily determine a Tech news source won't publish news under economic category. (Or will, that's the problem.)

Most of the cases news title won't be touched, it remains in the original form at the most. So Category, Title, and Publish Date a good starting point to group news into one.

If you detect problems with the methods above you need some fine-tuning under the hood.

Maybe you need to read the whole article and compare two (thousands of) articles word-by-word.

- There are a lot of stopwords that can distort the comparison, so you'll need to ignore these.
- You may want define synonyms (J Lo = Jennifer Lopez)

If the raw texts of news are similar (you can define a threshold value) you can compare the other factors again (described above).

Some news sources providing good tagging in the RSS source, maybe you can use this too but not rely on it.

And remember, you'll need a lot of fine-tunings at the start (about 1 year) then you'll be fine.

Comment: Dear Fabrik, thanks for your reply... is there any algorithm or code available for this.

Comment: The bad news: you should write your own. The good one? I've provided a lot of useful infos ;)

Answer (score 4):

I read somewhere - but I do not have a reference - that Google News uses a variant of MinHash to detect near-duplicate news posts. And a lot of them are almost identical, coming from a press agency only with minor adaptions by the newspapers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinHash

has a reference and the statement that Google News used a variant of LSH and MinHash:

> Das, Abhinandan S. et al. (2007), "Google news personalization: scalable online collaborative filtering", Proceedings of the 16th international conference on World Wide Web. ACM

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any question here, but I would start by developing some sort of fingerprint algorithm, with words, names, titles, dates etc from the articles. Then I would check the similarity of the fingerprints to find identical articles, maybe by some sort of MapReduce job to easily spread the work to different servers in a cluster.

If you want some inspiration, check out the source code for Google Living Stories:
http://code.google.com/p/living-stories/

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try Jaccard Coefficient or Jaccard Similarity

The Jaccard index, also known as the Jaccard similarity coefficient (originally coined coefficient de communauté by Paul Jaccard), is a statistic used for comparing the similarity and diversity of sample sets. The Jaccard coefficient measures similarity between finite sample sets, and is defined as the size of the intersection divided by the size of the union of the sample sets.
[Jaccarrd Coefficient.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)

I think Facebook uses this as well as some eCommerce stores to group their related products, posts, etc. You can take a look at these other links here on Stackoverflow for guide.

- [How to find "related items" in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153062/how-to-find-related-items-in-php)
- [MySQL / PHP: Find similar / related items by tag / taxonomy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019976/mysql-php-find-similar-related-items-by-tag-taxonomy)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do some form of document clustering.  This involves:

- Breaking articles down into "features" (for example, a TF-IDF vector
  of keywords)
- Having a similarity metric (for example, cosine similarity, that can take two articles and decide how similar they are)
- A clustering algorithm, that uses the similarity metric to break articles down into clusters.

Since this is news and you have new articles coming in, you will probably need an "online" algorithm rather than a batch one.  Search for incremental DBSCAN as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I have has success doing this using by dumping all the articles into Elsasticsearch and doing a [more_like_this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) query. This works surprisingly well. It just took some fine-tuning to get some of the settings right. You can also use a free Elasticsearch hosted instance at [bonsai.io](https://bonsai.io/)